# Does C++ have templating literals like javascript?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am looking for a templating literals feature like the one that was introduced to ES6 JavaScript. Is there something comparable?

**Javascript:**

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(`Liftoff in ${i} seconds`)
}
```

I am looking for a clean way to iterate through several directories using a for loop.

Comment: No the closest you can get is to use either a 3rd party library like [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), using [`std::printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) semantics, or waiting for C++20 which will have [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Comment: It's called "string interpolation".

Comment: @SergeBallesta It has nothing to do with compilation. Kotlin has string interpolation, even though it's a compiled language.

Comment: @aedm: I am a too old dinosaur for that. I loved C language because it had a very simple yet very powerful syntax. I then loved C++ when it added OO to that simple and powerful language. Modern C++ is now far too complex for me, and still does not allow to build a true 2D container over a contiguous 2D memory array. But I must admit that it is more a rant than an objective opinion :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have C++20 available, you could use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Here's a usage example from the linked page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("Hello {}!\n", "world");
}
```

If you don't have C++20 yet, Boost has [a similar feature](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.format).

Comment: Or fmtlib if C++20 is not available: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt